# Make the multicolumns in a row equally sized?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have some big tables and I want to know how it is possible to make the columns in a row all equally sized. You can see in the row  'Intra Prediciton' that the column with the content 'I_PCM' is bigger than the others in its row. Same with '16x8' and '8x8' in the next row. Is it possible to fix that?

Here the image:

[image]

I also appreciate other suggestions how to improve the tables.

heres the mess ...

```
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.8} } c|}
    \newcolumntype{N}{>{\columncolor[gray]{.8} \color{gray}}  c|}

%Spaltenzahl 8
% \color{gray} \color{lightgray} %\rowcolor{hellgrau} \cellcolor{dunkelgrau} 
    \begin{tabular}{|       >{\color{white}  \columncolor[gray]{.2}[.5\tabcolsep]}      c       |       >{\columncolor[gray]{.8}[.5\tabcolsep]}     c        |      >{\columncolor[gray]{.8}[.5\tabcolsep]}     c       |       >{ \columncolor[gray]{.8}[.5\tabcolsep]}        c   |       >{ \columncolor[gray]{.8}[.5\tabcolsep]}        c   |       >{ \columncolor[gray]{.8}[.5\tabcolsep]}        c       |   >{ \columncolor[gray]{.8}[.5\tabcolsep]}        c   |   >{ \columncolor[gray]{.8}[.5\tabcolsep]}        c    } 
\hline
Bildverfahren                                                   &           \multicolumn{3}{Y}{progressive}     &  \multicolumn{3}{Y} {interlaced } \\  
\hline
Frames/Slices                                                   &       \multicolumn{2}{Y}{I}       &       \multicolumn{2}{Y}{P}       &   \multicolumn{2}{Y}{B}       \\
\hline
 Slices                                                                             & \multicolumn{3}{N}{nein}   &  \multicolumn{3}{Y}{ja}  \\ 
\hline
Transformation                                              & \multicolumn{2}{N}{8x8 DCT}       & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{8x8 IDCT} & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{4x4 IDCT} \\
\hline
Adaptive Quantization                   & \multicolumn{2}{N}{nein} & \multicolumn{2}{N}{Lumi} & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{Variance} \\
\hline
Max. Ref Frames                                         & \multicolumn{3}{N} {keine} & \multicolumn{3}{Y}{16} \\
\hline
B-Pyramid                                                               &\multicolumn{3}{N} {nein} & \multicolumn{3}{Y} {ja} \\
\hline
Loop-Filter                                                                 & \multicolumn{3}{N} {nein} & \multicolumn{3}{Y} {ja} \\
\hline
Entropiekodierung                                   & \multicolumn{3}{Y} {CAVLC} &  \multicolumn{3}{Y}{CABAC} \\
\hline
SubPixel ME                                                         &  \multicolumn{2}{N} {nein} & \multicolumn{2}{N} {halb} &  \multicolumn{2}{Y}{viertel} \\
\hline
Intra Prediction                                                & \multicolumn{1}{N} {nein} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{16x16} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{8x8} &  \multicolumn{1}{Y}{4x4}  &\multicolumn{2}{Y}{ I\_PCM}\\
\hline
MB-Partitionierung                                  & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{16 x 16} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{8x16} & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{16x8} & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{8x8} \\
\hline
SubMB-Partitionierung                   & \multicolumn{1}{N}{nein} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{8x8} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{4x8} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{8x4} & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{4x4} \\
\hline
%Intra Prediction & \color{gray} nein  & 16×16 & 8×8 &  4×4  \\
Farb-Sampling                                                   &           \multicolumn{2}{Y}{4:0:0}       & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{4:2:0} &  \multicolumn{1}{Y}{4:2:2} &  \multicolumn{1}{Y}{4:4:4} \\
\hline
Bit-Tiefe                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{8}  & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{8 bis 10} & \multicolumn{2}{Y}{8 bis 12} & \multicolumn{1}{Y}{8 bis 14} \\
\hline
Error Prevention /Handling  &  \multicolumn{3}{N} {nein} &\multicolumn{3}{Y}{ja} \\
\hline
Level/Profile                                                       &  \multicolumn{3}{N} {nein} &\multicolumn{3}{Y}{ja} \\
\hline
    \end{tabular}
```

EDIT:

Isn't that cool? Used tablet now...
[image: my cool table]

Unfortunately the vrules are sometimes not so beautiful. You see it when comparing the last two lines. Should I color the table?

Comment: without any source shown we can not really help, but in general if you use `p{2cm}` rather than `c` as the column type then you can control the column widths exactly.

Comment: You will need to provide some code. The table also has some parts that appear structurally wrong. What is the relation of the 'nein' and 'ja'cells to "P"?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it seems OP wants _centered_ columns of the same width. Moreover, the table shows some columns-and-a-half or so entries. I'm sure I could cobble up something with `p{xxx}`, assorted `\multicolumn{}` and centering text in the column. But I shudder at the mess that will result.

Comment: with all respect this table is just terrible. Different contrasts, wrong column sperators vertical lines that don't divide for human readers etc. Just scratch that and make a readable one.

Comment: you dont think it looks nicely? awww....

Comment: No, it doesn't look nice; is there any relation between, say, "interlaced" in the first row and "ja" in the third one? Or between "P" in the second row and "8x8 IDCT" in the fourth one? I don't think so. The shape of your table, instead, suggests there is.

Comment: I dont see an alternative form of stucturing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I don't like the layout you are trying to produce, since I think it is very confusing for the reader, here is some coding that will produce equally spaced cells in a particular column.

[image: Sample outptu]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\tabelt}[1]{\hfil\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1 \hss}\hfil}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|@{}>{\hbox to 9cm\bgroup}{c}<{\egroup}@{}|}
\hline
x and z&\tabelt{A}\vrule\tabelt{XX}\vrule\tabelt{ZZZ}\strut\\
\hline
yy or pp&\tabelt{BBB}\vrule\tabelt{C}\vrule\tabelt{DD}\vrule\tabelt{P}\strut\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If the row has a non-standard height, then the final `\strut` will have to be replaced by an appropriate version of `\vrule width 0pt height 14pt depth 4pt`.

The basic idea of the code is that `\tabelt` produces a variable width box with its contents centered, but of zero width.  To make the first and last boxes correct, the table specification includes `@{}` to kill spacing added between columns.  To prevent everything collapsing the width of the column is specified.

A similar idea will work in `\multicolumn`:

[image: Multicol output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\tabelt}[1]{\hfil\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1 \hss}\hfil}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  First line & Some interesting random column text & and more & and more\\
\hline
  Second line&\multicolumn{3}{>{\unskip}{c}<{}@{}|}{\tabelt{BBB}\vrule\tabelt{C}\vrule\tabelt{DD}\vrule\tabelt{P}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here will kill extra spacing at the beginning with `\unksip` and the `\strut` is no longer necessary.

### Update: Usage with `colortbl`

The first solution works with `colortbl` with very little modification:

[image: Version 1 with colour]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,colortbl,xcolor}
\newcommand{\tabelt}[1]{\hfil\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1 \hss}\hfil}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{red}\color{white}}c|%
  @{}>{\columncolor{green}[0pt][0pt]%
  \hbox to 9cm\bgroup\color[gray]{0.7}}{c}<{\egroup}@{}|}
  \hline
  x and z&\tabelt{A}\vrule\tabelt{\color{black}XX}\vrule\tabelt{ZZZ}\strut\\
  \hline
  yy or pp&\tabelt{\color{black}BBB}\vrule\tabelt{C}%
  \vrule\tabelt{DD}\vrule\tabelt{P}\strut\\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

For the second version, using `\multicolumn`, one has adjust the code some what, since `colortbl` produces its alignments uses `fill`s instead of `fil`s (in attempt to stop the user doing what we are trying to do :-) :

[image: Version 2 with colour]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,colortbl,xcolor}

\newcommand{\tabelt}[1]{\hfill\hbox to 0pt{\hss #1 \hss}\hfill}

\begin{document}

\showoutput
\begin{tabular}{|>{\columncolor{red} \color{white}}c|%
  >{\columncolor{green}}c|%
  >{\columncolor{green}}c|%
  >{\columncolor{green}}c|%
  }
  \hline
  First line & Some interesting random column text & and more & and more\\
  \hline
  Second line&\multicolumn{3}{>{\unkern\unskip%
  \columncolor{green}[0.5em][24em]\color[gray]{0.7}}{c}<{}|}%
  {\tabelt{BBB}\vrule\tabelt{C}\vrule\tabelt{\color{black}DD}\vrule\tabelt{P}}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. The first solution is working, but the in the second solution the content of the for columns with the characters (b,c,d,p) in the second line are all colapsed in the center. Why is that?

Comment: You need to make sure the columns you are spanning have non-zero (actually sufficiently large) width.  This is done in two different ways in my examples.  Alternatively you can force entries to have some minimum width by redefining `\tabelt` with the `0pt` replaced by a non-zero width, e.g.`\newcommand{\tabelt}[1]{\hfil\hbox to 5em{\hss #1 \hss}\hfil}`

Comment: `\usepackage{colortbl}` - the trouble maker. I removed it from my document and now the second example works also for me. Thanks.

Comment: puhh... seems that I need this package though. Do you know how to fix that, or an alternative?

Comment: See my update for use with `colortbl`.

Comment: am I right that the first solution will be problematic when one column is bigger than the half of the table?

Comment: Well, your original question has a problem in that situation too: if you have n elemnts you want equally spaced and one is wider than the space available divided by n, then there is going to be some overlap.  Of course, if you drop the `\vrule`s between elements, this will be less noticable.  One possibility would be to split a long entry of over several lines, e.g. using a `\parbox`.

Comment: How would you do such a table? It seems that my layout is not the best. But what is the alternative?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7541/discussion-between-andrew-swann-and-user25646)